# Animating to a variable in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm animating several elements at once and the final properties of some elements depend on the properties of the other elements. For example, I something like `$('#a').animate({height:$('#b').height()})`, but `$('#b').height()` changes during the animation. Is there a way to make the animation finish at the final `$('#b').height()`?

Comment: Nope, not really. Once the values are passed to animate, the speed and start / end values are given. You could try rerunning the animation every time `$('#b').height()` changes with `$('#a').stop().animate({height: $('#b').height()})`

Comment: How do you compute the new height of `#b`? That would be helpful.

Comment: How is `$("#b").height()` defined? An example on http://jsbin.com would help understanding what you want.

Comment: What do you mean with "current `$('#b').height()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to animate the height of `#a` to match the **final** height of `#b`, i.e., the height the element has after the animation.

You can achieve this by updating the `end` value of the `fx` object in the step function. Example:

```
var $a = $('#a').animate({height: 50}, 2000);

$('#b').animate({height: $a.height()}, {
    duration: 2000,
    step: function(now, fx) {
        if (fx.prop === 'height') {
            fx.end = $a.height();
        }
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nm53M/) (note: I got the element names the other way round)

This of course only works if the second animation is at least as long as the animation it depends on.

More info in the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/animate/).